# Filter matched rows and un-matched rows as Dataframes via Pandas Dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe for a csv, and a datafrom for a row from database.

**csv_df**

```
   Id Location Name
  0        y    y
  1        n    y
  2        y    n
```

**rule_df**

```
Location Name
    y    n
```

I want to filter the `csv_df` based on the `rule_df`, so that the result is two result sets, one where all columns match those in the `rule_df`, the other data set where any one column doesn't match any one column in the `rule_df`.

**Expected Result**

Rows matched

Both `Location` and `Name` match to those in `rule_df`

```
Id Location Name
2        y    n
```

Rows don't match

```
Id Location Name
0        y    y
1        n    y
```

The code below works partially, but cannot get the expected result:

```
csv_df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Id':['0','1','2'],
                        'Location': ['y', 'n', 'y'], 
                       'Name':['y','n','n']})
rule_df = pd.DataFrame({'Location': ['y'], 'Name':['n']})

print('csv_df', csv_df)
print('rule_df', rule_df)


for col in rule_df.columns:
    print(rule_df[col].name, rule_df[col].values[0])
    criterion = csv_df[rule_df[col].name].map(lambda x: x.startswith(rule_df[col].values[0]))    

print('rs:',csv_df[criterion])
```

**Not Expected Result**

```
rs:   Id Location Name
1  1        n    n
2  2        y    n
```

**Update**

Sorry for the confusion and not specifying clearly.

Please see below the added requirements and changes.

1.Both `cvs_df` and `rule_df` contain more than two columns, e.g. 10-30 columns. The solution should be able to handle more than two columns in both `xx_df`.

2 Both `cvs_df` and `rule_df` contain data like below:

```
  csv_df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Id':['0','1','2'],
                            'Location': ['', 'LD', ''], 
                           'Name':['Tom','','']})
    rule_df = pd.DataFrame({'LocationRequired': ['y'], 'NameRequired':['n']})
```

**Expected Result**

Rows matched

Both `Location` and `Name` match to those in `rule_df`

```
Id Location Name
1        LD
```

Rows don't match

```
Id Location Name
0            Tom
2
```

**Update 3**

Sorry again for the confusion and not specifying clearly.

Please see below the added requirements and changes.

1.The `cvs_df` contains more than two columns, e.g. 10-30 columns.

2 The `rule_df` contains more than one row.

2 Both `rule_df`  and `rule_df` contain data like below:

```
  csv_df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Id':['0','1','2'],
                   'Location': ['', 'LD', ''], 
                      Name':['Tom','','']})
#column names whose value must be not empty
rule_df = pd.DataFrame([['Location']],
                          columns= ['ColName'])
```

**rule_df**

Below only the Location column whose value must be not empty, but it could be more than one mandatory column.

```
  ColName
0  Location
```

The expected result is the same as the Update above.

**Expected Result**

Rows matched

Both `Location` and `Name` match to those in `rule_df`

```
Id Location Name
1        LD
```

Rows don't match

```
Id Location Name
0            Tom
2
```

Comment: I don't figure out why you are getting wrong result but this can be achieved by inner join on Location and Name.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer, pls see my update to my question. Sorry for the confusion and the changes.

Comment: The update is in contradiction with the first part (which was the original question). You mention that more columns are present in the real problem. How are they supposed to match (between `csv_df` and `rule_df`)? Is it by position (`csv_df.iloc[:, 1:]` to match with `rules_df`) or is it by name (after removing the `'Required'` suffix in `rule_df`)? Does `rule_df` always contain a single row? If so, why not use a `Series` instead? Why is `rule_df` containing strings `'y'` and `'n'` instead of a `bool` value?

Comment: pls see my update 3. Sorry for the confusion and the changes. This will be the last update.

Answer (score 0):

**Error** is your example **csv_df** dataframe in end is different from your **csv_df** dataframe mentioned in very starting.

```
# It is not aligned with your example in starting 
# Name - y, n, n
csv_df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Id':['0','1','2'],
                        'Location': ['y', 'n', 'y'], 
                       'Name':['y','n','n']})
                       
It should be -> Name - y,y,n
csv_df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Id':['0','1','2'],
                        'Location': ['y', 'n', 'y'], 
                       'Name':['y','y','n']})
```

Below code gives required output using **JOINS**

```
csv_df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Id':['0','1','2'],
                        'Location': ['y', 'n', 'y'], 
                       'Name':['y','y','n']})

rule_df = pd.DataFrame({'Location': ['y'], 'Name':['n']})

pd.merge(csv_df, rule_df, left_on=['Location','Name'], right_on=['Location','Name'],how='inner' )
```

**First Output :**

[image]

**Second Output:**

```
pd.merge(csv_df, rule_df, left_on=['Location','Name'], right_on=['Location','Name'], how='left',indicator=True ).\
query("_merge == 'left_only'").drop('_merge', axis=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer, pls see my update to my question. Sorry for the confusion and the changes.

Comment: pls see my update 3. Sorry for the confusion and the changes. This will be the last update.

Answer (score 0):

Build a mask, then slice:

```
mask = csv_df[rule_df.columns].eq(rule_df.squeeze(), axis=1).all(1)
# [False, False, True]

df_match = csv_df[mask]

df_diff = csv_df[~mask]
```

output:

```
# df_match
  Id Location Name
2  2        y    n

# df_diff
  Id Location Name
0  0        y    y
1  1        n    n
```

##### update

If the rules dataframe define the columns that should not contain null/empty data, define the mask with:

```
m = rule_df.squeeze().eq('y')
mask = csv_df.add_suffix('Required')[m[m].index].fillna('').ne('').all(1)
```

Then, as above:

```
df_match = csv_df[mask]

df_diff = csv_df[~mask]
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer, pls see my update to my question. Sorry for the confusion and the changes.

Comment: See update in the answer

Comment: It works. Please could you provide tutorial links for beginners like me to understand your answer? is it somewhere here or elsewhere? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/index.html

Comment: I don't have any tutorial to provide. I am principally using the official doc as reference. Quick explanation of the above code. We convert your ref dataframe to Series with `squeeze` keep only the indices that match `y`. We use those to select the columns in which we check that no value is absent using `eq` and aggregation per row with `all(axis=1)`. All those functions are described in the pandas doc in details.

Comment: What is the purpose of `m[m]`, `m[m].index`,  and  `csv_df.add_suffix('Required')[m[m].index]`?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer, pls see my update 2. Sorry for the confusion and the changes.

Comment: Please feel free to keep your previous answers. Thanks again.

Comment: pls see my update 3. Sorry for the confusion and the changes. This will be the last update.